# Scheduler command is not working at midnight in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-scheduler

I have setup a command to run every Saturday at midnight but it is not working
I write this but not running

```
$schedule->command('weeklyRewardPoints')->weeklyOn(6, '00:00')->timezone('Asia/Dubai');
```

then I try this but again not working

```
$schedule->command('weeklyRewardPoints')->weeklyOn(6, '0:0')->timezone('Asia/Dubai');
```

Even I tried to run at any specific minute at midnight like this but still not working

```
$schedule->command('weeklyRewardPoints')->weeklyOn(6, '00:30')->timezone('Asia/Dubai');
```

It is working successfully any other hour and minutes but not at midnight hour and minutes

this is my cron job

```
* * * * 6     php /home/path-to-my-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: the scheduler is supposed to run every minute, which would be `* * * * *`

Comment: @lagbox Thank you so much. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler)

> So, when using Laravel's scheduler, we only need to add a single cron configuration entry to our server that runs the schedule:run command every minute.

the scheduler need cronjob needs to run every minute

```sh
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

your scheduler runs every 6 minutes.

You can furthermore write

```php
$schedule->command('weeklyRewardPoints')->weeklyOn(6)->timezone('Asia/Dubai');
```

and remove the time from `weeklyOn` as it is predefined with `0:0`.

Comment: thank you for telling me this. I did not know that we have to run cron every minute on server